# Bounds of ordinary differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to show that the solution for the following equation $$\ddot{x}=-\log x-1$$ is bounded for every initial condition.
I started by converting to the system $\cases {\dot{x} = y \\ \dot{y}=-\log x - 1}$ and I reached the following expression for phase lines $(x,\pm \sqrt{2(C-x\log x)})$, where $C$ is constant. Clearly the derivative of $x$ is bounded, but I don't know if it is related. Am I in the right direction? Is there something better I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any conservative system of the form $\ddot x=-f'(x)$ one gets the first integral
$$
E=\frac12\dot x^2+f(x)
$$
by multiplying with $\dot x$ and integrating.

All solutions are restricted to the set $f^{-1}((-\infty,E])$ where the constant $E$ is determined by the initial conditions. Now if the graph of $f$ has the form of  a trough, all solutions remain in bounded regions.

Comment: Has the form of a trough? Do you mean that f is convex? I don't understand.

Comment: No, convex is not necessary, only that the function goes in both directions towards infinity. What is not the case for $f(x)=x\ln x$ on $x\ge 0$. What happens when $x$ reaches $0$? Perhaps change the potential to $f(x)=|x|·\ln|x|$ to avoid that boundary.

Comment: I still don't understand. I see why $U(x) \in ( - \infty , E ]  $ but what do I know of $U^{-1} ( U (x) ) = U^{-1} ( E - \frac{ { \dot{x} } ^ 2 }{2} )$ ? Why it is bounded?